# Correct and Incorrect Answer Count

Tags: vb.net, winforms, counter

I want to add a counter for my program that basically counts the times I answered correctly and incorrectly.

When a user adds or subtracts correctly the correct label shows 1 and when a user correctly answers again the correct label should show 2. It just adds and adds until the program is running. Same goes for the incorrect label.

Does anyone know any simple solutions?

Comment: Simple solutions to what? We don't know what part of this simple program is giving you a problem.

Answer (score 1):

You did not mention what programming language you want to use. I am going to tell you for C#.

1 Initialize both labels lblCorrectAnswer and lblWrongAnswer with 0, as counter starts with zero.

2 On answer button click event you can check if given answer is correct and store result in blnAnswer.

```
if(blnAnswer == true)
   lblCorrectAnswer.Text += int.Parse(lblCorrectAnswer.Text) + 1;
else
   lblWrongAnswer.Text += int.Parse(lblWrongAnswer.Text) + 1;
```

Comment: Sorry. I doing the program in windows forms application visual basic Thank you for the response!

Comment: Here is my code:

If txtAnswer.Text = nMathSum Then
        lblCorrect.Text += Integer.Parse(lblCorrect.Text) + 1
        ElseIf txtAnswer.Text <> nMathSum Then
        lblIncorrect.Text += Integer.Parse(lblIncorrect.Text) + 1
        End If

When i run the program it shows me a error